# In xampp 1.7.4 pdftk doesnt work it gives UNLINK error

Tags: php, xampp, pdftk

In my previous version of xampp **pdftk** was working fine ... later when i upgraded it **xampp 1.7.4**... the pdftk is not working in this version ... how to overcome this problem without downgrading my xampp version

Comment: Perhaps [this thread](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=44123) will help?